# UnityWebRequest POST not sending Body

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

As the title says, the code is as below. I have tried setting chunkedTransfer=false, Content-Type application/json, WWWForm, building the JSON object manually, and HttpClient. For Content-Type application/json, the API isn't even hit. For the rest, the body is an empty object. I have no idea what the issue is here looking through StackOverflow, YouTube, Unity documentation, and all the other resources.

As of this morning I am using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize the JSON body. I think the biggest issue right now is that when I set `webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` the API route doesn't even receive the request.

```
async Task<string> makeRequest()
        {
            string url = API_BASE + "/users"; 
            
            Dictionary<string, string> body = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            body.Add("username", username);
            body.Add("password", password);
            body.Add("email", email);

            using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)))
            {
                await webRequest.SendWebRequest();

                string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webRequest.downloadHandler.data);

                if (webRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                {
                    JSONNode error = JSON.Parse(result);

                    registerAndLoginError.GetComponent<Text>().text = error["error"]["message"];
                    registerAndLoginError.SetActive(true);

                    return "";
                }
            }

            BasicLogin();
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: How did you import `JsonConvert` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I had seen this solution elsewhere, but I continued ignoring it because it's hacky af and seems like something that should be addressed. However, I'm at the point of not caring right now.

1. Use `UnityWebRequest.Put` instead of `UnityWebRequest.Post`
2. Set `webRequest.method = "POST";`
3. Set `webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`

This works, but it feels really bad and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Exactly this. Sadly, it is still the case with Unity 2021.3.8f1.

Comment: Also, see this thread in the Unity forums about potential future developments: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-post-url-jsondata-sending-broken-json.414708/

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `JsonUtility` **does NOT support `Dictionary`!** It follows the same serialization rules as the Inspector, see [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html).

=> The `JsonUtility.ToJson(body)` will just return `""` or in best case `"{}"`.

Try to rather create the JSON string "manually" like e.g.

```
var json = "{\"username\":\""+username+"\", \"password\":\""+password+"\", \"email\":\""+email+"\"}";
```

or use a different library like e.g. `Newtonsoft .NET Json` (available as [Package via the PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html)) which supports direct (de)serialization of collections and Dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did actually try that too, I forgot to include it. Same issue.

Edit: Updated to include the JSON object manual creation attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I used all of the methods above and im still being told my body is blank {}

Whats somewhat hilarious is i used

```
private IEnumerator SendScores(int score)
{

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("score", score);
    form.AddField("module_id", _moduleID);
    form.AddField("user_id", _userCode);

    Debug.Log(form);
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://pbs-web-git-sc-14-order-and-payment-system-pbs-labs.vercel.app/api/scores", form);

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
        Debug.Log("Response: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }

    QuizManager.Instance.ResetQuizScore();
}
```

and sending it as a form actually got accepted by the API.

When i went to do it later though once again im getting told the API is receiving a empty body.

when i send it to a mock API though the JSON version and the FORM version are both posting a correctly formatted body as sent.